# How to get a server's host key using JavaScript in the browser?

Tags: javascript

Given the hostname of a server, I want to get its Host/Public key (stored in `/etc/ssh/`) using JavaScript in the browser.

I am aware that in the command line, we can get a host key using the `ssh-keyscan` utility. I want to do the same thing using JS (preferably vanilla JS).

Comment: You cannot. Browser JavaScript is not able to connect to arbitrary ports. (Spawning a command from browser JS is also impossible.)

Comment: In your server you can get the public SSH key using your preferred method. Then you can set an HTTP header containing it for each response and finally access your key from any browser by getting the headers. If you don't want to send the key on every response you can implement any logic you want to filter cases. There is absolutely no way to access it from a remote browser without making some changes server-side.

Comment: `Spawning a command from browser JS is also impossible.`


Ah, yes, I realize that now, thank you will edit it out of the question.

For anyone looking for a reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211118/execute-a-shell-command-upon-a-click-event-in-a-web-page

Comment: @user3840170 Assume that I try to get the host key in my backend JS server, is there a vanilla JS solution to getting the key then?

Answer (score 0):

A Node.js script could probably do it a few different ways.

- it could execute the same `ssh-keyscan` command a human would use, via the built-in `child_process` module

You would capture the content of stdout and stderr as strings, and then parse those strings manually.

- if the data you want can be read directly from a file, you could use the `file` module to read the file contents as a string, which you would then parse manually

Both of those will work using vanilla JS, and would not require that you install any third-party modules.

Note that Node might need special permissions. You might not encounter that difficulty running this on your local workstation, as yourself, but in a security-conscious environment it will probably require special steps.